# Minimum number of lines to make set of lines connected

Tags: computational-geometry, connected-components

Suppose we have a set S of n line segments, with k connected components. I am trying to solve the problem of finding the minimum number n0 of lines we to add to S to connect the set, with the condition that new lines must share both extremes with any of the lines in S.

My thoughts: the exact solution can be found by exploring all combinations of segments joining points from two different components. This is, however, incredibly expensive for a big set S. I believe we can use some heuristic, like joining first more distant points, but since there is no lower bound to the problem (for example, a set S formed by aligned vertical lines can be connected by a single line) I don't think we have a better option than exploring all combinations.

Is there any theory on the topic I can use? How could approximate solutions be built?

Comment: Do you allow ends of new segments touch old ones inside them (not at the ends)? If yes, then any algorithm, joining only end points of segments, might not give you the minimum number of new segments. Any comments?

Comment: @HEKTO Yes, that is allowed. I added the condition of touching one extreme to make the search space finite. I don't know how to address the problem without this condition

Comment: Interesting question... If to compute a convex hull for each connected component, then this problem will be reduced to finding a minimum set of stabbing lines for a set of convex polygons. However, I'm not aware about any algorithms for that, so I asked a question on CS -  please see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/minimum-stabbing-problem-for-a-set-of-convex-polygons